# Is it possible to do novel-scale writing on a Chromebook?

Tags: novel, tools, software

I've been looking into Chromebooks for their portability and cost and was wondering what kind of writing tools, if any, exist on the platform that could be used to write larger projects without making one go insane.

Comment: I wrote my first book on my Chromebook and am working on my second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That very much depends on what you need to write with.

If you *need* the likes of Scrivener then you are going to have some issues working efficiently on a Chromebook (I'm not sure what Chrome apps there are)

However, if you can adapt your writing style to what you have available you will find that there are many tools available.

Personally I have found that google docs to be a perfectly functional word processor for writing in. The ability to create a a metadata file with links etc works well enough.

Although I have recently stopped using even those, I have now moved over to using a basic text editor [well not too basic](https://atom.io/) and storing all of my files on a private [github](http://github.com) repository.

Remember that even in this modern world there are still a large number of authors who use a typewriter, or a pen and paper.

Its all about your approach and how you organise it. Maybe sidestepping the technology will let you focus more on what you're writing (I know it did for me)

Of course your mileage will vary...

Comment: Exactly. You can write fine using Google Docs, which integrates with ProWritingAid for easy cleanup. A Chromebook is probably the most affordable effective portable writing solution available right now. But you could never pull me off of Scrivener, and for that you'd need a to buy a MS Surface or used Mac notebook computer.

Comment: @Kitsune I do mostly write in text files, but I do love my Surface! Absolute perfect mix of tablet and laptop.

Comment: @MichaelB: Do you use any plugins for atom? It looks like a great platform but I've not used it much.

Comment: @user2859458 There's a wannabe developer in me that thinks it would make an excellent base to be an open source contender to scrivener! One day I might start coding it. Until then the only extension I use is word count. It is basically notepad with spellcheck for me.